# Sorting and Filtering List of Objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, time-complexity

I am having an external service from where I get all employees details of an organization like as shown below. I am using java8 and spring cloud feign client for consuming the service

```
[
  {
    "employee": {
      "empId": "empId123",
      "name": "Emp1",
      "houseNumber": "5",
      "firstName": "firstName1",
      "lastName": "lastName1",
      "city": "city1",
      "band": "A"
    },
    "type": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "employee": {
      "empId": "empId456",
      "name": "Emp2",
      "houseNumber": "7",
      "firstName": "firstName2",
      "lastName": "lastName2",
      "city": "city2",
      "band": "B"
    },
    "type": "ABC"
  }
  :
  :
]
```

The employees details service has around 10000+ employee details.

I have a requirement to create another two service

1. Sort based on **city** and **houseNumber** and return all employees
2. Service for filter employees based on certain attributes like **city**, **band**, **empId** etc.

At present for Sorting Service I am using like as shown below

```
final List<Employees> employeesList = employeeService.getAllEmployees().stream()
                .sorted((emp1, emp2) -> p1.getAddress().getCity().compareTo(emp2.getAddress().getCity()))
                .sorted((emp1, emp2) -> p1.getAddress().getHouseNumber().compareTo(emp2.getAddress().getHouseNumber()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For filtering I am using the below code

```
String cityName = "some city name"...

final List<Employees> employeesfilteredList = employeeService.getAllEmployees()
    .stream()
    .filter(employee -> employee.getAddress().getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(cityName == null ? "" : cityName))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but my customer who is a technical guy says this has performance issues and asked to bring something which takes less time complexity (best to be **O(1)**) for bringing the result

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the current approach which I'm using and is there any way in which I can improvise it in any other way or approach

Comment: 1. Your sorting is wrong: its sorts by city, and then sorts all the elements again by house number. 2. There is no way to sort or filter a list in O(1). Sorting is O(n*log(n)), and filtering is O(n). The best approach would be to let the external service do this filtering and sorting by delegating that task to its database, rather than loading everything in memory, sending everything over the network, deserializing everything, and the filtering out most of them.

Comment: Seriously? The house number has precedence over the city? And what about the street? Besides that, you can avoid sorting multiple times, you can avoid performing a redundant `null` check in every predicate evaluation, but you can not change the time complexity. A linear list is a linear list. When the underlying service does not provide something better, there is nothing you can change about it. Oh, and `Employees` is a bad name for a class which models a single employee per instance...

Comment: Thanks **JBNizet** and **Holget**  for the reply. Just a thought not sure whether I am right or not, how abt maintaining it under a hashtable has O(1) in insertion, search and deleteion (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l56sp.png)

Comment: @AlexMan You're looking mostly at the time complexities of Get, Insert and Delete. While what you're intending to do in your service is Sort, Filter etc. There is a difference.

Comment: If you can afford to call the external system once, then store the results in a HashMap, and use that HashMap for all the subsequent requests, without getting fresh values from the external system, then don't use a HashMap. Use a database, with the appropriate indices, and use it to filter and sort the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I could think of that you can certainly improvise is the call to `sorted` twice which can be made only once:

```
// replacing with 'employees' for 'employeeService.getAllEmployees()'
Comparator<Employees> compareBasedOnCity = 
            Comparator.comparing(emp -> emp.getAddress().getCity());
Comparator<Employees> compareBasedOnHouse = 
            Comparator.comparing(emp -> emp.getAddress().getHouseNumber());
employees.sort(compareBasedOnCity.thenComparing(compareBasedOnHouse));
```

and another during filter is to avoid treating `null` and `""` string as same:

```
List<Employees> finalList = employees.stream()
            .filter(employee -> employee.getAddress().getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(cityName))
            // don't consider empty city name same as null (think of "  " otherwise)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, as already pointed out by both [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021649/sorting-and-filtering-list-of-objects-java8-with-less-time-complexity/53021851#comment92945671_53021649) and [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021649/sorting-and-filtering-list-of-objects-java8-with-less-time-complexity/53021851#comment92945637_53021649), none of this brings down the complexity from say `O(nlogn)` to `O(1)` as you're expecting.

Comparing it further with operations like Access, Insertion and Deletion is not equivalent either. Since the operations performed their are different as well.

Comment: ...and *if* you want to treat a `null` search string like `""`, you only need to do it once, before the stream operation, `String searchTerm = cityName == null ? "" : cityName; List<Employees> finalList = employees.stream()  .filter(employee -> employee.getAddress().getCity() .equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm)) 
 .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @nullpointer thanks for the reply....out of curiosity can you tell me how this sort `employees.sort(compareBasedOnCity.thenComparing(compareBasedOnHouse));` perform better than what I have used....

Comment: @AlexMan the second comparator is only queried for element pairs which the first comparator considers equal. In contrast, two sorting operations are always two sorting operations. In the worst case, the entire first sorting operation is obsolete.